# how to check the given instruction is using array in LLVM

Tags: llvm

What I want to ask is that can we check a given instruction is containing an array as operand in LLVM. I am writing a pass and stuck at this phase.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can check this with following code:

```
Instruction *I;
bool UsingArray = false;
for (unsigned num = 0; num < I->getNumOperands(); ++num)
  if (isa<ArrayType>(I->getOperand(num)->getType()))
    UsingArray = true;
```

Comment: @neel, if it is not working, then operand has other type, not `ArrayType`.

Comment: @neel, I think this question is connected with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033920/count-number-of-arrays/

Comment: these are different question, for example : int a[10] will be counted as aray allocation using isArrayAllocation() but if we have say int b = c + a[3]; in this case how will you check is it using Array or not

Comment: @neel, in your example a[3] is not array, it is integer and have type of array element.

Comment: Thanks @vkorchagin that helped me. Just to add you can identify if I is a load instruction (which will be the case if a[3] is stored in memory) then perform `Value* v=I->getPointerOperand()` for a load instruction and then call `isa<GEPOperator>(v)` to detect if a GEP instruction is used. I guess this is the only way an array can be loaded from memory. Correct me if I am wrong.