# Count number of arrays

Tags: c, llvm, clang

How can the total number of arrays be counted in a C program ?

The array declarations in LLVM IR correspond to *alloca* type of operation. 
So

```
int a[10];
```

corresponds to

```
%a = alloca [10 x i32], align 4
```

in LLVM IR.

But I also noticed that

```
 int j = 0;
```

also corresponds to an alloca instruction

```
 %j = alloca i32, align 4
```

So how to count the number of alloca instructions that correspond only to arrays ?

**EDIT:**

```
  for (Function::iterator i = F.begin(), e = F.end(); i != e; ++i)
  {
      for (BasicBlock::iterator ii =(*i).begin(), ii_e = (*i).end(); ii != ii_e; ++ii) 
      {
           Instruction *n = dyn_cast<Instruction>(&*ii);
           for( int num = 0; num < n->getNumOperands(); ++num)  
            if(isa<ArrayType>(n->getOperand(num)->getType()))
        {
              // doesn't work
          errs()<<"yayayayay Array\n";
        }
       }
   }
```

Comment: count with what ? A shell script ? C Code ? The easiest thing is to parse the line and see if you have `alloca [ .... x .... ],` or `alloca ....,` isn't it ?

Comment: @Eregrith I am using a LLVM C++ Pass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AllocaInst` has public method `isArrayAllocation()`. You can use it to count the number of alloca instructions that correspond only to arrays.

```
for (Function::iterator BB = F.begin(), BE = F.end(); BB != BE; ++BB)
  for (BasicBlock::iterator II = BB->begin(), IE = BB->end(); II != IE; ++II)
    if (AllocaInst *AI = dyn_cast<AllocaInst>(II))
      if (AI->isArrayAllocation())
        errs() << "Alloca of array is found!\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Open [the LLVM demo page](http://llvm.org/demo/) and compile following code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int a[10];
  return 0;
}
```

to the LLVM C++ API calls.

This is how `a` created:

```
AllocaInst* ptr_a = new AllocaInst(ArrayTy_6, "a", label_9);
```

where `ArrayTy_6` is:

```
ArrayType* ArrayTy_6 = ArrayType::get(IntegerType::get(mod->getContext(), 32), 10);
```

So, to find out if `alloca` instruction you are looking at is defining array, just do `isa<ArrayType>()` on it's first argument.

See [LLVM docs](http://llvm.org/doxygen/annotated.html) for more info.

Comment: Please See the edited question. "isa" doesn't helps in detecting the array

Comment: Maybe `->getType()` is not needed?

Comment: Without gettype it gives an error. I tried this simple code as well
n->getType()->isArrayTy(). This too doesn't work. I am not able to get where I am wrong